# Consume WCF secured with SSL certificate in a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, certificate

I hosted a .svc WCF in IIS 6.0. I added a reference to that web service in a winform application. However, when I call any method of my service I get a System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

I have the certificate installed in my personnal store.

Here's my server config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAwsService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://teclpo02.srr.fr:1098/AwsService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAwsService" contract="wsAws.IAwsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAwsService"/>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="AuthWorkStation_Wcf_Web.AwsService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="AuthWorkStation_Wcf_Web.IAwsService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate storeName="Root" findValue="CA_SRR_DISTRIB" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Do I have to edit my winform app.config file ? Do I have to write some line of code to tell where is the certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have transport security which requires SSL/Https. But your address is http.

Change your address to https

From the code you posted:

```
 <client> 
   <endpoint address="http://teclpo02.srr.fr:1098/AwsService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAwsService" contract="wsAws.IAwsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAwsService"/> 
 </client> 
<services>
```

You are also spesifying the port number that post could be blocked.

Comment: The client section is used to call another web service in my wcf. I can read the wsdl of my secured wcf in my browser by typing HTTPS://myserver/Service.svc?wsdl. So this isn't the issue in this case I think.